# Масштабирование изображения спрайта

Tags: css, изображения

Суть: есть спрайт и на нём не в масштабе пикча. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способ масштабировать итоговое изображение спрайта (уменьшить/вписать размером в букву) через css, не прибегая к фотошопу?

[image: phone]

```css
.telephone
        border: 1px solid red
        &::before
          display: inline-block
          background: url(../img/css_sprites.png) no-repeat
          background-position: -340px -240px
          height: 50px
          width: 50px
          border: 1px solid red
          content: ''
          margin-right: 8px
```

```html
<div class="telephone">8 (123) 456 78 90</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, ваш спрайт имеет размеры 400*320 px и размеры иконок в нем 40*40 px.
Положение вашей иконки - 6-я слева во 2-м ряду сверху. Соответственно, при масштабе 1:1 для показа ее нужно задать `background-position:X Y`,  где X = -200 (`200 = 40px * (6-1)`), Y = - 40 (`40 = 40px * (2-1)`). При этом  неявно подразумевается, что `background-size`  вашего спрайта равен его реальному размеру, т.е., 400*320.

Вам надо задать размер иконки, равный размеру шрифта.  Поехали:

1. Для начала задайте высоту элемента, который эту иконку содержит, равной высоте шрифта, например, 16 пикселей,  и пропорциональную ширину (для квадратной иконки - тоже 16 пикселей) .
2. Рассчитайте `background-size`. Если вы поставите его как 100%, в элемент вместо одной иконки влезут ВСЕ, поэтому это значение нужно увеличить во столько раз, во сколько одна иконка меньше всего спрайта. Если в процентах, то для ширины это значение будет `100%*(400/40)`, высоту оставить `auto` для сохранения пропорций.
3. Аналогично рассчитайте `background-position`. В нашем примере это будет X = -80 (`80 = 16px * (6-1)`), Y = - 16 (`16 = 16px * (2-1)`).

Но проще использовать псевдоэлемент, которому задать стилями трансформации.